# "Não o se nega" ou "não o-se nega" ou "não o-se-nega"?

Tags: gramática, pronomes-oblíquos

Pelo que sei, é desaconselhado usar dois pronomes oblíquos que não se contraem num mesmo verbo. "Te + a" = "ta"; além de "te", são possíveis "me", "lhe", "nos", "vos" e "lhes".

Porém, não é impossível e acontece; ex.: "sabe aquele martelo? O me traz!", como meu pai disse uma vez. Sendo assim, como se deve escrever?

Comment: Não se inicia frases com pronomes oblíquos. O correto é: *Traz-me o.* e *Não o se nega*

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, põe isso numa resposta para eu poder dar up-votes ou down-votes. Na tua terra diz-se "não o se nega"? Soa a "não o sonega"... No norte de Portugal diríamos "não se o nega", talvez "não se lho nega".

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, sim, mas é comum na fala brasileira, por isso que coloquei.

Comment: @ANeves "Não se o nega" e "Não o se nega" são equivalentes (segundo a norma), assim como "Traz-me" ou "Traz-mo" (como na resposta abaixo). Aqui, coloquialmente, falariam: "Não se nega", "me traz" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A contração é sempre obrigatória entre os clíticos dativos *me*, *te*, *lhe*, *nos*, *vos* e *lhes* com os clíticos acusativos *o*, *os*, *a*, *as*. (Não se inclui aqui a combinação *se* + *o*, possível nalguns dialetos; esta nunca é contraída em *so*).

Posto isto, temos:

> Sabes aquele martelo? Mo traz.

Na variedade europeia contudo, a colocação dos clíticos antes do verbo (próclise) é proibida nesta situação (o mesmo segundo as regras estabelecidas para língua padrão no Brasil). Nesse caso, o correto seria:

> Sabes aquele martelo? Traz-mo.

O uso destas contrações é relativamente incomum na oralidade, mesmo em Portugal. Normalmente é possível eliminar um dos pronomes:

> Sabes aquele martelo? Trá-lo aqui.
> O tal martelo, dei-te a ti ontem.

Comment: Então, o correto é "não o se nega" ou "não se o nega", certo?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu escrevi bem mal a pergunta.

Comment: Eu uso bastante *mo, to, lho;* menos ou mesmo raramente *no-lo, vo-lo*. São provavelmente as minhas raízes rurais. E o dialeto com que cresci, zona de Torres Vedras, é precisamente um desses que admite *se* (indefinido) + *o* = *so*, tipo "Que é que se faz a este milho?" -- "Dá-so às galinhas."

Comment: @Jacinto, legal. Eu não sabia que existia "so".

Comment: @Jacinto, "so" se fala como "sô" ou "su"?

Comment: @Schilive, pronuncia-se como *su*, análogo a *mo, to, lho*. Diz-se na região onde eu cresci, zona rural uns 50 km  a norte de Lisboa, e talvez noutras; não é padrão. Nunca vi escrito.

Comment: @Jacinto, desculpa pelo último comentário, ele é meio besta.

Comment: @Schilive ao ordem é _não se o nega_, _não se vo-lo nega_. A ordem mantém-se na ênclise: _nega-se-lho_.